# Elasticsearch - generic facets structure - calculating aggregations combined with filters

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, facet

In a new project of ours, we were inspired by this article http://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/#generic-faceted-search for doing our “facet” structure. And while I have got it working to the extent the article describes, I have run into issues in getting it to work when selecting facets. I hope someone can give a hint as to something to try, so I don’t have to redo all our aggregations into separate aggregation calculations again.

The problem is basically that we are using a single aggregation to calculate all the “facets” at once, but when I add a filter (fx. checking a brand name), then it “removes” all the other brands when returning the aggregates. What I basically want is that it should use that brand as filter when calculating the other facets, but not when calculating the brand aggregations. This is necessary so the user can, for example, choose multiple brands.

Looking at https://www.contorion.de/search/Metabo_Fein/ou1-ou2?q=Winkelschleifer&c=bovy (which is the site described in the above article), I have selected the “Metabo” and “Fein” manufacturer (Hersteller), and unfolding the Hersteller menu it shows all manufacturers and not just the ones selected. So I know it’s possible somehow and I hope some one out there has a hint as to how to write the aggregations / filters, so I get the "correct e-commerce facet behavior".

On the products in ES I have the following structure: (the same as in the original article, though “C#’ified” in naming)

```
"attributeStrings": [
    {
        "facetName": "Property",
        "facetValue": "Organic"
    },
    {
        "facetName": "Property",
        "facetValue": "Without parfume"
    },
    {
        "facetName": "Brand",
        "facetValue": "Adidas"
    }
]
```

So the above product has 2 attributes/facet groups – Property with 2 values (Organic, Without parfume) and Brand with 1 value (Adidas).
Without any filters I calculate the aggregations from the following query:

```
  "aggs": {
    "agg_attr_strings_filter": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "agg_attr_strings": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attr_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributeStrings.facetName"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "attr_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue",
                    "size": 1000,
                    "order": [
                      {
                        "_term": "asc"
                      }
                    ]
   } } } } } } } }
```

Now if I select Property "Organic" and Brand "Adidas" I build the same aggregation, but with a filter to apply those two constraints (which is were it kind of goes wrong...):

```
  "aggs": {
    "agg_attr_strings_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Property"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Organic"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "attributeStrings"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Brand"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Adidas"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "attributeStrings"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_attr_strings": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attr_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributeStrings.facetName",
              },
              "aggs": {
                "attr_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue",
                    "size": 1000,
                    "order": [
                      {
                        "_term": "asc"
                      }
                    ]
   } } } } } } } }
```

The only way I can see forward with this model, is to calculate the aggregation for each selected facet and somehow merge the result. But it seems very complex and kind of defeats the point of having the model as described in the article, so I hope there's a more clean solution and someone can give a hint at something to try.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> The only way I can see forward with this model, is to calculate the aggregation for each selected facet and somehow merge the result.

This is exactly right. If one facet (e.g. *brand*) is selected than you can not use global brand filter if you also want to fetch other brands for multi-selection. What you can do is apply all **other** filters on selected facets, and **all** **filters** on non-selected facets. As a results you will have `n+1` separate aggregations for `n` selected filters - first one is for all facets and the rest are for selected facets.

In your case query might look like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg_attr_strings_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Property"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Organic"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "attributeStrings"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Brand"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Adidas"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "attributeStrings"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_attr_strings": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attr_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributeStrings.facetName"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "attr_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue",
                    "size": 1000,
                    "order": [
                      {
                        "_term": "asc"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "special_agg_property": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                      "value": "Brand"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                      "Adidas"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "attributeStrings"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "special_agg_property": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_filtered_special": {
              "filter": {
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetName": "Property"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "facet_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "size": 1000,
                    "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "special_agg_brand": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                      "value": "Property"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                      "Organic"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "attributeStrings"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "special_agg_brand": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_filtered_special": {
              "filter": {
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "attributeStrings.facetName": "Brand"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "facet_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "size": 1000,
                    "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query looks super big and scary but generating such query can be done with few dozen lines of code. 
When parsing query results, you need to first parse general aggregation (one that uses all filters) and after special facet aggregations. From the upper example, first parse results from `agg_attr_strings_filter` but those results will also contain aggregation values for *Brand* and *Property* that should be overwritten by aggregation values from `special_agg_property` and `special_agg_brand`
Also, this query is efficient since Elasticsearch does good job in caching separate filter clauses so applying same filters in different parts of query should be cheap.

> But it seems very complex and kind of defeats the point of having the model as described in the article, so I hope there's a more clean solution and someone can give a hint at something to try.

There is really no way around the fact that you need to apply different filters to different facets and at the same time have different query filters. If you need to support "correct e-commerce facet behavior" you will have complex query :)

*Disclaimer*: I'm coauthor of the mentioned article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and input on this. (And sorry about the late feedback - the flu got the better of me.) It does make total sense, it just seemed very verbose when thinking about it, so really nice to get your thoughts on this, also regarding performance in ES. If anyone else wants to do the same, read "hakaa's" answer carefully, as it provides create hints that I wish I had read more careful at first. :)

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very old thread but I'm wondering if someone can clarify for me: while this solution seems plausible, my knowledge of ElasticSearch is very limited, but I'm learning fast: how can this multi-aggregation actually work as described, if they are computed on the resultset? If, for example, I have a list of book 'bindings' (paperback, hardback, etc.) and filter my results by 'paperback', how can I ALSO get binding aggs for other bindings as described, if the results dictate the aggs in the first place? Should the agg be in a different scope? Can it be done in a single query?

Comment: @hakaa is this applied using a post_filter?

Comment: If you are like me and wondering which answer to follow, use this one. Why? Because if you want to show all possible selections from a certain selection you have to have N+1 queries. 
A reference can be found here https://medium.com/swlh/faceted-navigation-for-e-commerce-with-elasticsearch-dbf82bdeb7d4

Answer (score 11):

The issue comes from the fact that you are adding a filter on `Property` and `Organic` **inside** your aggregation, hence the more facets you pick, the more you will restrain the terms you will get. In that article, the `filter` they use is in fact a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-post-filter.html), both names were allowed until recently, but `filter` [got removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_top_level_literal_filter_literal_parameter) because that was causing ambiguities.

What you need to do is to move that filter outside the aggregations into the `post_filter` section, so that the results get correctly filtered out by whatever facets have been picked, but all your facets still get computed correctly on the whole document set.

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                        "value": "Property"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                        "Organic"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                        "value": "Brand"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                        "Adidas"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "attributeStrings"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_attr_strings_full": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attributeStrings"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "attr_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributeStrings.facetName"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attr_value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue",
                "size": 1000,
                "order": [
                  {
                    "_term": "asc"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "agg_attr_strings_filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "attributeStrings",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Property"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Organic"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "attributeStrings",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetName": {
                            "value": "Brand"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "attributeStrings.facetValue": [
                            "Adidas"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "attributeStrings"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "attr_name": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "attributeStrings.facetName"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "attr_value": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "attributeStrings.facetValue",
                  "size": 1000,
                  "order": [
                    {
                      "_term": "asc"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have a post_filter, with the same conditions as in the aggregations, so the result (hits) are correct in that regard. (Sorry for leaving that out - I was trying to boil down JSON to something manageable...)

The problem with leaving out the filter in agg, is that it will always show the aggregations for the full query, which is not what I want either. The filters should change when other filters are selected.

Comment: (Sorry for hitting enter for save earlier - post contined):


Fx. looking at the site I linked to above with no filters, the "Max. Scheibendurchmesser (mm)" contains:
115 (9) 125 (46) 150 (10) 180 (11) 230 (20)
But selecting the manufacture (Hersteller) Metabo, the other aggregations/filters updates and "Max. Scheibendurchmesser (mm)" contains:
115 (3) 125 (16) 150 (5) 180 (4) 230 (5)

Comment: What you can do is to keep the `post_filter` (in order to make sure the result set matches the selected facets), then in your aggregations you can have one with the filters (to know which facets are still available with the facets selected and which I called `agg_attr_strings_filtered`) and another without the filters (to show the full set of available facets in case the user wants to select another and which I called `agg_attr_strings_full`). I've updated my answer

Comment: I still don't think it gets me totally what I want. Say eg. I select one property and one brand, then it should only show the brands having the property and vise-versa the properties from the products from the selected brands and I can't see how I can merge the data from the two aggregations to achieve that. Anyway, thanks a lot for your ideas and time ! I think that I'll have to rewrite each attribute into it's own aggregations instead to gain more control over the filter part of the query.

Comment: Feel free if you want to re-assign the bounty to hakaa instead ;-)

Comment: Hi I am trying to achieve similar to this I have facets of Brand and Guarantee for example (as well as many others) but have found that I cannot use filter in this example as it is no longer supported in ES

Comment: @rs82uk post_filter you mean?

Comment: To get this running in ES 6.8 add a aggregation name in `agg_attr_strings_filtered` in between 
`"... aggs": { "nested": { "path": "attributeStrings ..." `

Like `"aggs": { "filters": { "nested": { "path": "attributeStrings"...`.